# How to check if my call back function works

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
void poseCallback(const mera::lonaConstPtr &msg){  
        int i;  

        static tf::TransformBroadcaster br;
        tf::Transform transform;   
        transform.setOrigin( tf::Vector3(0,0,0));
        transform.setRotation( tf::Quaternion(1,1,1));
        br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform, ros::Time::now(), "world", "madar_link"));
```

How do I know if this works. Are there any commands which can help me to know if this will work

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71857/how-to-check-if-my-call-back-function-works/) by [Bodgan Mircu](https://answers.ros.org/users/5830/bodgan-mircu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-08-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-08-08**:
ROS_ERROR? Or any other print function?

**Comment by [Bodgan Mircu](https://answers.ros.org/users/5830/bodgan-mircu/) on 2013-08-08**:
@TommyP can you please elaborate on this? Should I just put something like ROS_INFO("See if it works"); insite my poseCallback function to check if its printing or something like that. I dont know how does ROS_ERROR works. Thanks

**Comment by [dPackard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4911/dpackard/) on 2013-08-09**:
To check if your function callback "*works*" is slightly different than checking if the function callback is "*being executed*" ;)  - but yes, add ROS_INFO("Executing poseCallback"); as the very first line of your function. If that function is being executed, you will see it in the log messages.

**Comment by [Bodgan Mircu](https://answers.ros.org/users/5830/bodgan-mircu/) on 2013-08-11**:
@dPackard I tried to do this but I cannot visualise my log messages. The only way to visualise log message is via rqt_console? Am I right. When I try to check it via rqt_console nothing appears. I cannot see any messages

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-08-11**:
The printout is also in the shell from where you started the program. If you start with launch file give the --screen flag to roslaunch otherwis you will not see all printouts (ROS_ERROR you will see without --screen)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you've included a ROS_INFO statement in your callback, and that message doesn't show up in rosconsole or the terminal where you started the node, then your cb is not being executed.

There are a few possible reasons that your callback would not be executed... but I'm going to guess at a couple likely reasons since you don't run into any build errors. I'm guessing that this is a callback for a subscribed topic. The callback for a subscribed topic is *only executed when new data is published* to the topic you've subscribed to.

This suggests  that **A)** no data is being published to the topic you are subscribed to, or **B)** you are subscribed to a topic that doesn't exist

The rostopic and rqt_graph tools can help you investigate these possibilities.

- http://www.ros.org/wiki/rostopic
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt_graph
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics

---

Originally posted by [dPackard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4911/dpackard/) with karma: 115 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dPackard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4911/dpackard/) on 2013-08-12**:
If this didn't help, please update your question with more details describing your exact situation (e.g. how you registered the callback in your code, what is the output of `rostopic echo <topic name>`, of `rosnode info <node name>`, etc), and maybe someone can help you find an exact solution

**Comment by [Bodgan Mircu](https://answers.ros.org/users/5830/bodgan-mircu/) on 2013-08-12**:
@dPackard first of all, thanks for such a detailed answer. After some debugging I have figured out that the call back function does not work for me. However its not because of the 2 reasons you mentioned above [(A) no data is being published to the topic you are subscribed to, or B) you are subscribed to a topic that doesn't exist)] . Becuase when I do rostopic echo /mytopic then I can see information on the console which shows information is being published on the topic. Also when I subscribe I use the same topic /mytopic. I will try to debug my code further and try to figure it out. Thanks

**Comment by [dPackard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4911/dpackard/) on 2013-08-12**:
Good luck! It sounds like you are on your way to figuring it out :D

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use one of the print function, like @TommyP said. Its very easy to use, and there is not a greate different if you use ROS_INFO or ROS_ERROR, that just means the Logger Level you use, [http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxconsole#Logger_Levels].

I mostly use the ROS_DEBUG("....") Method to make sure my callbacks work fine.

---

Originally posted by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) with karma: 336 on 2013-08-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4